# Can't push branch to github

Tags: git, github, branch, push, git-remote

I forked a github repo and cloned the fork to my machine. Then I created a new branch from `master` called `#25` (the issue's ID I want to fix). I fixed the bug and commited to by branch. Now I'm trying to push this branch to github, so I can send a pull request, but it doesn't work. Even though I followed the instructions, the branch won't show up on github.

```
$ git push origin #25
Everything up-to-date
```

I'm on the correct branch:

```
$ git branch
* #25
  master
```

And the commit was also successful:

```
$ git log
commit 083f15035feab5af1673ed3685e10cca6e24aeeb
Author: John Example <johnexample@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 5 14:53:16 2012 +0100

    Fixed #25: Window now correctly resizes to fullscreen.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `git push origin #25:#25`.

Comment: @vcsjones Same result, unfortunately.

Comment: Cool question. I wonder how did you create this branch.

Comment: @the.malkolm I have to admit, I didn't create the branch on the shell, otherwise I would have realized that it's not a good idea (`git branch #25` just lists the branches). The developers of SourceTree didn't forget to properly escape `#`. Now I'm still getting an error, but I'm a step closer.

Comment: +1 epic fail. Reminds me of my first C program, which I called `test`. Took a while to figure out why `printf` didn't seem to work. (Yes, running  `./test` worked much better!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

# - is a symbol used to prefix any comments i.e.

```
$ ls
$ ls #holymotherofgod
```

Are exactly the same

You have to escape it

```
$ git push origin \#25
```

Comment: Irony: you had to escape it in your post, too.

Comment: Should this also work, if I only have a `master` branch on github and `#25` only exists locally?

Comment: Yes, just tested myself. Why not?

Comment: Oh right, I had a typo, sorry. Thanks for helping me to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
git flow feature finish #25
```